# prompt user to enter every row of a N*N array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array N*N , where `N` is from user input, and I want to prompt user to enter every row separately.  I don’t know how to do it because `N` is not constant.

This is the code:

```
System.out.println("Enter number of nodes\n");
    int V = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("\nEnter matrix\n");
    int[][] graph = new int[V][V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < V; j++)
            graph[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: Create additional variable U after `for-i` loop, before `for-j` loop, say U = scan.nextInt(); and change j < V to `J < U`.

Comment: `nextInt()` only returns numbers 0-9. If the number of nodes are more than 9 this will not work.

Comment: @Gendarme number of nodes is up to 30

Answer (score 2):

try

```
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter row " + (i+1) + "\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < V; j++)
            graph[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: i have done this before , code will not compile it give the error "cannot find symbol graph[i][j] = scan.nextInt(); 
symbol: variable i"

Comment: Please make sure you've added "{" sign at the end of the first for loop row, and the closing "}" at the end of the loop. This defines the scope of the "i" variable.

Comment: thanks , my bad i forgot to add the "{}" it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Enter %d integers for row %d/%d (delimited by spaces): ",
                      columns, i+1, rows);
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        array[i][j] = input.nextInt();
}
```

**Output**

> Enter the number of rows: 4
>   Enter the number of columns: 3
>   Enter the numbers in array:
>   Enter 3 integers for row 1/4 (delimited by spaces): 1 2 3
>   Enter 3 integers for row 2/4 (delimited by spaces): 4 5 6
>   Enter 3 integers for row 3/4 (delimited by spaces): 7 8 9
>   Enter 3 integers for row 4/4 (delimited by spaces): 10 11 12